# How does one implement an attribute-triggered advice in spring?

Tags: spring-aop, spring.net

I am looking to use AOP to do some timing of calls. I want to statically decorate the methods with a custom attribute and then have the advice invoked (around) so that it takes a timestamp, makes the call and then takes a timestamp to determine the time span.

It seems simple but I cannot find how to do such a thing.

Details:

- I am using Spring.NET (yes, it is dead but this is legacy code)
- Here is my C# code extracted to remove proprietary details:

First of all, here is the Attribute.  Pretty straightforward:

```
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class TimingAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public string TheAuditField { get; }
        public TimingAttribute(string auditField)
        {
            TheAuditField = auditField;
        }
    }
```

Second, the Advice class:

```
    public class AuditTimingAdvice : IMethodInterceptor
    {
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (AuditTimingAdvice));
        public object Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation)
        {
            Logger.Info("In AuditTimingAdvice");
            var result = invocation.Proceed();
            Logger.Info("After the call");
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Third, here is the XML for the service context for configuring Spring.NET

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <description>Definitions of objects to be exported.</description>

  <object id="AuditTimingAdvice" type="Spring.Aop.Support.AttributeMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="advice">
      <object type="SpringDotNetAopTestbed.AuditTimingAdvice, SpringDotNetAopTestbed"/>
    </property>
    <property name="attribute" value="SpringDotNetAopTestbed.TimingAttribute, SpringDotNetAopTestbed" />
  </object>

  <!-- Service -->
  <object id="TheServiceImpl" singleton="false" type="SpringDotNetAopTestbed.Service1, SpringDotNetAopTestbed" >
  </object>

  <object id="TheService" type="Spring.Aop.Framework.ProxyFactoryObject, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="target" ref="TheServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
      <list>
        <value>AuditTimingAdvice</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>

</objects>
```

Finally, here is an example of how I would want to use the attribute:

```
    public class TargetExample
    {
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (TargetExample));
        public void MethodOne()
        {
            Logger.Info("In Method one");
        }

        [Timing("full")]
        public void MethodTwo()
        {
            Logger.Info("In Method two");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `AuditTimingAdvice.Invoke()` never gets entered.

Comment: Could you please update the question with sample code that you have tried ? Spring AOP examples are not at hard to find . Also explain *statically decorate the methods with a custom attribute* . An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would always help others to understand your requirement better.

Comment: On SO you are expected to show sample code and explain what problem you had with it. So this question does not fit here. And besides, did you ever use a search engine? [Timing methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+aop+timing) is ***the*** classical example for AOP in any programming language.

Comment: Reasonable point.  I extracted the code to isolate the details.